# Kodi goes transparent with CLI overlayed

Tags: raspbian, kodi, terminal

I have a project setup that allows for a car installation of an Audio Receiver

[Audio Receiver Code](https://github.com/BaReinhard/Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install-Car-Install)

I currently have Kodi setup the autorun on boot. Around 10+ minutes the Kodi screen becomes transparent with a transparent CLI (also transparent) overlayed on top. Audio still plays fine and you can navigate Kodi with the remote, but it pretty much ruins the reason for having Kodi active.

I have tried using `setterm -powerdown 0` to no avail. After plenty of research I am still at a loss as to why this is happening.

I am using the Raspbian Jessie update of 1/11/17

Comment: Looks fairly involved. Have you checked [Kodi's logs](http://kodi.wiki/view/Log_file/Advanced) to see if there's anything out of the ordinary happening? Does the CLI show any indication as to why it's been launched?

Comment: It pops up with the typical raspberry pi login. The pi is just sitting idle and shouldn't need any login prompt. Do you know of where the log files are for kodi?

Comment: Take a look at the link in my first comment.

Comment: Your question has "raspbian" tagged to it. What version are you using?

Comment: @MadMike update, 1/11/17 Raspbian Jessie

Comment: It seems something is opening a transparent terminal window while kodi is running. Have you tried to create a additional user and start kodi from this second user? Does it happen again? What if you don't start Kodi? Does the terminal still open?

Comment: @MadMike I'll have to try later, what I am doing is adding consoleblank=0 to the end of  /boot/cmdline.txt . I believe this should fix the issue, but I will write back when I get some testing done in an hour or so

Comment: @MadMike adding consoleblank=0 to the cmdline.txt file fixed the issue. It seems as the console goes to sleep mode or kodi, the console is being prompted to come up. The same happens whenever I ssh in and adjust the amixer volume. I am guessing any verbose output by the system will cause this. I'll try changing the tty in the cmdline to see if that will disable ssh verbosity from doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix of adding `consoleblank=0` to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file fixes the transparent CLI from overlaying on top of kodi. I believe you can disable the faded kodi screen somewhere inside kodi, most likely power saving or power management.